# Finding out number of straight lines and curves in a given edge (canny or sobel) image

Tags: opencv, curve, edge-detection, straight-line-detection

I have tried the [Hough](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) algorithm for straight lines, but it only detects outermost frame of image (most of the time as square). All the internal information is left out.

I actually want to count(store result) straight lines and curves in an given edge image.

I came across the concept of fourier coefficients, does that help in my case? because I saw the applications of it. They mention image analysis and in particular shape.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Azhar. Please post the code what have you tried so far.

Comment: Hey there! I have edited your question to hopefully provide a clearer problem statement and result in better answers for you. If you have any code or additional things you have tried, please edit further to help everyone understand the issue you are trying to solve.

Comment: @JeremyHarris Thank you for editing. I am a beginner ..I tried different snippets .. but could not understand.